# using parameter in SQL with LIKE keyword

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

from my C#-programm, I access a SQL Server 2008 Database. I have a table with a fulltextindex and want to search for an indexed entry:

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_categories WHERE page_title LIKE @title
```

When 'title' has no withespaces everything is fine, but when title does contain withespaces, the request fails. It throws no error, but the returned recordset is closed

```
command.ChangeParameter("title", title);

using (System.Data.IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteQuery())
{
  while (reader.Read())
    resultSet.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));

  reader.Close();
}
```

I cannot enclose the @title parameter with '', because then the Command-Object would interpret the @title as a string and not a parameter.

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_categories WHERE page_title LIKE '@title'
```

Anyone knows how I can use a parameter for the LIKE request when the title-parameter can contain whitespace?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
SELECT page_id 
FROM page_categories 
WHERE page_title LIKE '%' + @title + '%'
```

Comment: I want to match the exact string. Let's say, I have 'tool' and 'tool songs' in my database. When I search with title="tool", I want to get ONLY the row with the value 'tool', not 'tool songs'. But this would be the case, when I use wildcards ...

Comment: Then you should be able to do where page_title = @title.  Maybe you need to provide better examples...

Comment: What I want to do is relative simple: I have a table with a nvarchar-string and an id. I want to get the id(s) - i can't be sure that the nvarchar is unique - for a given string.

Answer (score 2):

alternatively to the ck's answer, you could do this:

```
command.ChangeParameter("title", "%"+title.Trim()+"%");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use LIKE to search a freetext index. You use CONTAINS or FREETEXT or similar.

Comment: Ah, thanks. But my problem remains the same: SELECT page_id FROM page_categories WHERE CONTAINS (page_title, @title) will not work, when the value of title contains withespaces. It throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT page_id 
FROM page_categories 
WHERE page_title LIKE '%' + @title + '%'
```

The `%` represents a wild char similar to the more common `*` outside SQL (Any string of zero or more characters).

You should make sure that in the calling code the parameter is trimmed via `.Trim()`.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) is the full reference of possible wildchars.

Answer (score 0):

I add the single quotes to the query:

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_categories WHERE page_title LIKE '' + @title + ''
```

If I try this with 'Contains' ( CONTAINS (page_title, '' + @tile + '') ), I get a syntax error.